# How to get the values ​from a table (option value)

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

have this table in html , in columns (col6 and col7) I have  elements

I would like to get all data from the table according to the options selected in the columns (col6 and col7)

my function even does the job well taking all the data from the table and storing it in an array,
the big problem is that I can't get only the selected value inside the columns (col 6 and Col7 ) I've tried several ways, but it always gets all the elements inside the

```js
function save_Table(){

    var myData = document.getElementById('tab').rows;

      data = []
        for (var i = 1; i < myData.length; i++) {
              el = myData[i].children
                my_el = []

                  for (var j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {
                      my_el.push(el[j].textContent );
                  }
                        data.push(my_el)
          }
  console.log(data)
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
```

```html
<table id="tab">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
            <th>Col 5</th>
            <th>Col 6</th>
            <th>Col 7</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>TEST</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>TEST</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td><select class="browser-default">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select></td>
            <td><select class="browser-default">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">2</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TEST</td>
            <td>124</td>
            <td>TEST</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td><select class="browser-default">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select></td>
            <td><select class="browser-default">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">2</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="save_Table()">Teste</button>
```

Comment: How are you calling `save_Table()`? Should that be run when you change your `<select>`s?

Comment: call save_Table() by a button outside the table

Comment: You should include that in your snippet.

Comment: I'm going to include the button with the save_Table() function

Comment: Your script doesn't even reference the `<select>` items; what have you attempted to include those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Element.textContent` literally grabs the text, and you need the `value` property of the child `select` form. A guard clause in your nested for loop should do the trick:

```
if (el[j].children[0]?.tagName == 'SELECT') {
    my_el.push(el[j].children[0].value);
    continue;  
}
```

```js
function save_Table(){
    var myData = document.getElementById('tab').rows;

    let data = []
    for (var i = 1; i < myData.length; i++) {
      let el = myData[i].children
      let my_el = []

      for (var j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {
          if (el[j].children[0]?.tagName == 'SELECT') {
            my_el.push(el[j].children[0].value);
            continue;  
          }

          my_el.push(el[j].textContent);
      }
      data.push(my_el)
    }
  console.log(data)
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
```

```html
<table id="tab">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
            <th>Col 5</th>
            <th>Col 6</th>
            <th>Col 7</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>TEST</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>TEST</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td><select class="browser-default">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select></td>
            <td><select class="browser-default">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">2</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TEST</td>
            <td>124</td>
            <td>TEST</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td><select class="browser-default">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select></td>
            <td><select class="browser-default">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">2</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="save_Table()">Teste</button>
```